# Error: 'kethrow' isn't a type. kethrow _ClientSocketException(error, request.url);

Tags: flutter

Building flutter application is giving an error.When i try to build my application the error is occured.
The error is:

```
**/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/io_client.dart:88:7: Error: 'kethrow' isn't a type.
      kethrow _ClientSocketException(error, request.url);
      ^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/io_client.dart:88:15: Error: Expected ';' after this.
      kethrow _ClientSocketException(error, request.url);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/io_client.dart:88:43: Error: Expected ')' before this.
      kethrow _ClientSocketException(error, request.url);
                                          ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/io_client.dart:48:30: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'IOStreamedResponse' doesn't allow null.
- 'IOStreamedResponse' is from 'package:http/src/io_streamed_response.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/io_streamed_response.dart').
package:http/src/io_streamed_response.dart:1
  Future<IOStreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) async {
                             ^
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 45s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**
```

How to fix this error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what even is `kethrow`? I think it just needs to be `throw`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error a few days ago. It is strangely from the dart file. Mine was 'heethrow'. I corrected it by following the link to the file: /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/io_client.dart.

How to go about it:

1. Open location `/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/` in *Visual Studio Code*
2. inside the `src` folder, open `io_client.dart`
   (make sure you're in the `io_client.dart` inside the `src` folder)

Once you're in `io_client.dart`, locate the place with the error: in your case, it says 88:7 that is, line 88 column 7. Scroll to line number 88 and change 'kethrow' to 'throw'

the errors in the other places as marked in the image below should be corrected and your `io_client.dart` should be error free.

*Note:* other files outside `io_client.dart` might mark red indicating errors but never mind. Just save your changes in the `io_client.dart` file and close the file. Once closed

Open your project again and run `flutter clean` in the terminal.

next run `flutter pub get`

next run `flutter pub upgrade`

run your app again, everything should work fine.

[image]

But I'd advise you don't always go into those files to edit anything. I did that because I've tried every possible solution and needed to deliver my work. I even installed Visual Studio for Windows as suggested by flutter doctor, but that was not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If its a file from Flutter-Cache and `flutter clean` doesnt fix it, delete the file manually and run `flutter pub get`. The error likely came from a unintentional keyboard-press after code from a library was highlighted after an Error was thrown (hence the wrong throw-type)

I was facing a similar issue and in my case the error went along the lines of "kthrow is not a type", i searched the web and found the information

- `flutter clean ; flutter pub get` (duh)
- `gradlew cleanBuildCache`
- and basically deleting every occurence of .gradle\cache in your system

Nothing really worked but tbh the error is super weird because there is a typo in a library-file. So either someone pushed wrong production code (which i dont think is the case for the lib im using), or the file opened itself while facing an error in debug mode and i accidently pressed 'k' on my keyboard... (after all it probably highlited the 'throw' part)

BUT `flutter clean` should've fixed that instantly and i thought the file would get deleted but it somehow still existed. But after manually deleting it and running `flutter pub get` everything was back to normal...

Answer (score 0):

go to io_client.dart file in line 88 change kethrow to throw